# Laplace distribution sampling

Tags: pdf, stata

Anyone know how to draw multiple times from a Laplace distribution in Stata? I want to run some Monte Carlo analysis and know that my data fits a Laplace distribution.

Comment: I don't know a dedicated function, but as I understand your question this would be one line using `generate` and wrapping the quantile function around a call to `runiform()`.

Comment: Thanks, my stats is weak, do you mind expanding on this?

Comment: Done. Sorry, I exaggerated. I think it needs two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample script. Naturally your scale parameter will be whatever it is. The location parameter is here zero by implication; if not just add it in.

```
clear 
version 10: set seed 2803 
set obs 10000 
scalar sigma = 1 
gen P = runiform() 
gen y = sigma * cond(P <= 0.5, log(2 * P), -log(2 * (1 - P)))
```

We can use a normal quantile plot as reference showing that the tail behaviour is quite different from the normal or Gaussian.

```
qnorm y
```

[image]

Many people prefer to see some kind of density estimate

```
kdensity y, biweight bw(0.2)
```

[image]

but the most critical graph is a dedicated quantile-quantile plot. This one uses `qplot` which you must install from the *Stata Journal* archive after a `search qplot` in Stata. Note that `@` is not a typo here: it is a placeholder for whatever would otherwise be plotted on the *x* axis.

```
qplot y, trscale(cond(@ <= 0.5, log(2 * @), -log(2 * (1 - @))))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, one more question: if I want to set the mean and st dev of the laplace how should I do it? Presumably, the sigma scalar sets the st dev of the function? I tested the code and it didn't seem to generate a distribution with sigma st dev though.

Comment: The location parameter is the mean (and median and mode). So, as already indicated, you just add it to the variable generated. The SD is sigma multiplied by root 2, as documented in any standard source, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution